# VS2008: change tooltip background color in text editor

Tags: visual-studio-2008, comments

I am configuring the colors of my text editor for C++ in Visual studio 2008.

Unfortunately, I can't find the option to modify the background colour of the "when you let your mouse on a method, a window will pop-up with the some information on that method"  (I have no clue what is the name of this "pop-up". (EDIT: it seems to be called tooltip)

Does anyone know?